# where_in codeigniter error if array is empty

Tags: mysql, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I'm using Codeigniter 2.  I'm trying to make a mysql query using Active Record. The problem is I got error when array passed to where_in is empty. I'm asking if there any way to ignore `where_in` condition if the array is empty

This the condition example :

```
$this->db->where_in('p.brand_id', $brands);
```

And this is the error I got :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND `p`.`brand_id` IN ()

Comment: dont be afraid , just show your query dude

Comment: @echo_Me: He *is*.  `$this->db->where_in('p.brand_id', $brands);` is appending a `WHERE IN` to the query.  The question is fairly clear.

Comment: Are you sure $brands is an array? If isn't it will fail... Check this [link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: @RocketHazmat the problem is right before that line. thats why i told him to show the code

Comment: @echo_Me It's a big query with `multiple join` so, i show you just what i want.
@Kurro1 I'm 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't call `where_in()` if the array is empty.

```
if(is_array($brands) && count($brands) > 0){
    $this->db->where_in('p.brand_id', $brands);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed in Active Record (`DB_active_rec.php` class) and I Added this code to Ignore `where_in` condition if values  array's empty. So it's works now for me. 
The code I added is between //@begin and //@end

```
 /**
 * Where_in
 *
 * Called by where_in, where_in_or, where_not_in, where_not_in_or
 *
 * @param   string  The field to search
 * @param   array   The values searched on
 * @param   boolean If the statement would be IN or NOT IN
 * @param   string
 * @return  object
 */
protected function _where_in($key = NULL, $values = NULL, $not = FALSE, $type = 'AND ')
{
    if ($key === NULL OR $values === NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    //@begin
    // Ignore where_in condition if values array's empty
    if(is_array($values) && empty($values))
    {
        return $this;
    }
            //@end

           // More method stuff
```